# How to know "domain" of VM?

Tags: qemu, virsh

It seems to me that I misunderstand something because of the fact that English is not my first language.
The problem is explicitly described in the question. I run Windows XP using qemu from Linux and I want to manipulate it using virsh. But I have no idea how to obtain the domain (name, id or whatever) of the guest vm. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Run a Command Prompt and type :

> wmic computersystem get domain

Or 
For the Domain name of a computer type

> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain"